# Html Tab with a Close Button

Tags: html, css, tabs

I want to have a tab with the title text and a closing button in either the top right or left corner. How can I achieve this?

Picture for clarification

```
=============================
| X                         |
|                           |
|         Text Here!        |
=============================
```

Here is what I have tried so far...

```
<li class="tabLi ui-state-default ui-corner-top ">
            <div>
               <input type="button" name="close_tab" class="close_tab_button"/>
               <a href="<c:url value="/ex.url"></c:url>"
               title="Test"> "Text Here!"</a>
            </div>
</li>
```

With the following CSS

```
.close_tab_button {
   background-image:url("/messaging-center/resources/images/close_button.gif");   
}
```

Currently what happens: The button pushes down the text and tab gets big, this happens because the input and the link do not overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give your button  `position:absolute`

```
.close_tab_button {
   background-image:url("/messaging-center/resources/images/close_button.gif"); 
   position:absolute;
   top: 5px;
   left:5px; 
}
```

> An element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and
>   thus takes up no space when placing other elements. (Article [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position))

Now your button won't push your text down

Answer (score 0):

Take a look and play with [it](http://jsfiddle.net/Code_me/4SrtT/)

This is the code you need :

```
$('.text').before().click(function(){
$('.text').fadeOut('fast');
});
```